# set a maximum width and height for an image

Tags: graphics, dimensions

I would like to define a maximum height and a maximum width for an image at same time. I suppose there must be a package to do this, but actually I'm unable to find it...

Comment: This answer is what helped me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341545/212071

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use the `keepaspectratio` key and define your graphics as:

```
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm,keepaspectratio]{image}
```

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{./graphics/amato}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{./graphics/cardtrick}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Experiment with images with different aspect ratios to see the effect.

Comment: -1, he asked about max allowable width of image (so actual image width may be lower), but in your answer we set width.

Comment: @IvanKush a good question to ask is why is this the accepted answer...

Comment: This answer is the solution because the image width is constrained to be up to `width` (and similarly for `height`) and the image will shrink as needed in order to satisfy the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 51):

If you load the package `adjustbox` with the `export` option, its keys are usable with `\includegraphics`: put the following in the preamble

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % also loads graphicx
```

and then use

```
\includegraphics[max height=<dimension>,max width=<dimension>]{file}
```

In this way the image will be scaled at the maximum size so that its width and its height will not exceed the two stated dimensions and no distortion will be made.

Comment: if you want to set width AND max width, then you can do it like this with the `adjustbox` package: `\includegraphics[width=300, max width=\textwidth]{file}`. Don't put the max width first, it has to come after width.

Comment: @IvanKush Also, the number of views of this question, currently 254k, is extremely big.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `graphicx` package as below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imagefile.pdf}
\caption{Caption of the figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

`imagefile.pdf` is the filename of your figure file and it can be .png, .jpg......etc.

Comment: Do you really need `keepaspectratio` when you only specify either `width` or `height` but not both?

Comment: When only `width` or `height` is specified the `aspect ratio` is automatically maintained by TeX. I have corrected the MWE accordingly. Thank you for noting it. Some how I over looked the same.

Comment: @HarishKumar This can lead to problems. Suppose you have an image equal to `textwidth` height but 1.5textheight it will disappear at the bottom and vice versa. Best to use both and `keepaspectratio`.

Comment: -1, he asked about max allowable width of image (so actual image width may be lower), but in your answer we set width.

Answer (score -2):

In text (for instance IEEE with 2 columns) you can use:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering{\includegraphics[width=9cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{Figure}} 
\caption{type your caption}
\label{give a label if you want to refer to it in the text}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is what the accepted answer already says (because the important part is the includegraphics line). Btw: `\centering` does not take an argument.