# Includegraphics maximum width

Tags: graphics, pdftex, conditionals, scaling

With `\includegraphics` I can give the width of the resulting image (which would be scaled).

How can I give a maximum width of the image? That is, if the original is smaller than X, I'd like to keep the smaller image, if the image is larger than X, then the image width should be X.

Using `pdflatex`/`graphicx`.

Comment: I think you need to program that explicitly.

Comment: You mean like `maxwidth` in ConTeXt :)

Comment: See package `adjustbox`

Comment: @JosephWright I think I'll try adjustbox first (works fine), but when the distribution is too old, I'll just go for @ StephanLehmke's answer. So you could post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Herbert's answer made it too simple for me to copy/paste ...

Comment: Actually this seems to be a duplicate of [Scale (resize) large images (graphics) that exceed page margins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6073), but that question is written unnecessary long and complicated.

Comment: @MartinScharrer right. I'd humbly ask to not close as duplicate because (as you write) I believe this question is more concise than the linked question.

Comment: @topskip: I agree and posted an `adjustbox` answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47245/set-a-maximum-width-and-height-for-an-image/47247

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For more exotic requirements `adjustbox` or `resizebox` are useful but you don't really need any additional commands for this (other than a local command just to access `@` commands more easily)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth#1{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>#1 #1\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth{1in}]{image}

\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth{1cm}]{image}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would have been even greater if the person who wrote the graphics package had exposed \Gin@nat@width by a local definition of \width as for other latex2e box commands to save needing the \makeatletter dance. Now, who was that....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I had the same thought when I studied `graphics/x` while writing `adjustbox`. There I provide the original width as `\width`.

Answer (score 18):

The `adjustbox` provides a `max width` key just for this purpose. If the package is loaded with the `export` option this key and most others  can also be used for `\includegraphics`.

Here the content is only resized if its current size is larger than the given width. It works basically the same way as the code in David Carlisle's answer.
If the `\adjincludegraphics` macro is used the original width can directly be accessed as `\width`. Note that this feature is not enabled for `\includegraphics` by the `export` option. However this can be done by making `\includegraphics` using `\adjincludegraphics` instead using `\let\includegraphics\adjincludegraphics` after loading `adjustbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example images
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% 'export' allows adjustbox keys in \includegraphics

\begin{document}

\hrule% to see \linewidth

\includegraphics[max width=\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}

\includegraphics[max width=\linewidth]{example-image-a4}

% With \adjincludegraphics (or \adjustimage) you can also use the original width as \width:
\adjincludegraphics[width=\ifdim\width>\linewidth \linewidth\else\width\fi]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newlength\MaxWidth \newsavebox\IBox
\MaxWidth=100pt

\newcommand*\IncludeGraphics[2][]{%
  \sbox\IBox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \ifdim\wd\IBox>\MaxWidth \resizebox{\MaxWidth}{!}{\usebox\IBox}%
  \else\usebox\IBox\fi}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{image}

\IncludeGraphics{image}

\IncludeGraphics[width=50pt]{image}

\end{document}
```

[image]