# Resize images to half of text width only if too big for page margin

Tags: graphics, scaling

I want the images I'm using that exceed the page's text width to be scaled down to half the text width. Images that aren't wider than the text width don't need to be scaled. I have one markdown document that I'm converting to both html and pdf using pandoc.

The following code is in the preamble.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{
\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
\else
    \Gin@nat@width
\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}
```

What syntax do I use to have maxwidth = x * \linewidth where x = .5 (or some other number)? This is the 5th line in code block.

Comment: Related [Scale (resize) large images (graphics) that exceed page margins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6073) and [Includegraphics maximum width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86350).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resize to half of `\linewidth` if it is wider than `\linewidth` then simply add a `0.5` in front of `\linewidht` in the *then* clause:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{%
\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    0.5\linewidth
\else
    \Gin@nat@width
\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}
```

There should also be a `%` after the `{`, otherwise you get a space there, which might cause trouble.

---

Note that the `adjustbox` package adds a `max width` key and also allows to use the original width ad `\width` with `\adjincludegraphics`. For this see my [answer to *Includegraphics maximum width*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96468/2975).

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to redefine `\includegraphics` just

```
\makeatletter
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    0.5\linewidth
\else
    \Gin@nat@width
\fi}
\makeatother
```

In the preamble should cause all graphics inclusions to respect that scaling.

Comment: This has the added benefit of still respecting options given to the \includegraphics command. For example, \includegraphics[draft]{path} works as expected using the above method. When using the \renewcommand method, latex complains.

Comment: Works great, but first line contains typo, should be: \makeatletter

Answer (score 1):

The following redefinition of `\includegraphics` allows for that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\makeatletter
\let\old@includegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][,]{%
  \setbox9=\hbox{\old@includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \ifdim\wd9>\textwidth
    \old@includegraphics[#1,width=.5\textwidth]{#2}%
  \else
    \old@includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \par
\noindent\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=50pt]{example-image-a}\par
\noindent\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth,height=50pt]{example-image-a} \par
\noindent\rule[1ex]{.5\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{document}
```