# Shrink table to fit on a page, or keep it as it is

Tags: tables, scaling

I am using

```
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{% ... %}
```

to fit a table which might be too wide onto a page by scaling it down.

However, my problem is that if the table is smaller than the column width, it gets scaled up, which looks really ugly, and, more importantly, it can then become too long to fit on the page.

So how do I change above to either shrink it or keep it the same, but not scale it up?

I need something along the lines of

```
\resizebox{min(\columnwidth,\originalwidth)}{!}{% ... %}
```

Comment: What do the double backslashes mean? Are you using some other software for producing the tables? In any case, the `adjustbox` package might help.

Comment: scaling tables (in either direction) should really be the very last resort. It results in non standard distracting font sizes that are not consistent with the rest of the document. It's almost always better to choose a smaller document declared size such as \small and/or fiddle with column widths rather than scale the table.

Comment: Related: [Resize images to half of text width only if too big for page margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96408/5764); [Scale (resize) large images (graphics) that exceed page margins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6073/5764) and [Includegraphics maximum width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86350/5764).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: "fiddling" presumes manual intervention, which isn't possible in the automatic creation of reports. But if you can give me an automated way of finding out what standard font size will make the table fit I'd be more than happy to use that... In the meantime I'll go with scaling...

Comment: @egreg: Indeed, they were there to escape cat-ing from R, forgot to remove those

Comment: `X` columns from `tabularx` package for example automatically adjust the column width to make the table total width fit the specified size. To choose a font size, a bit harder but perhaps save the table in a box and if it's too big reset \small

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Interesting. A might give that a go a bit later!

Comment: Related: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

With the `adjustbox` package you can say

```
\adjustbox{max width=\columnwidth}{...}
```

that will scale the contents only if it exceeds the `\columnwidth`, according to the documentation:

> A good example is `max width=\textwidth` which will limit large content to the text width but will not affect smaller content.

Of course `\textwidth` is just by way of example and any dimension can be used.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
 \begin{tabular}{p{.7\textwidth}}\lipsum[2]\end{tabular}}

\noindent\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
 \begin{tabular}{p{1.5\textwidth}}\lipsum[2]\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As suggested by Martin Scharrer in a comment, the environment form can be even handier in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{p{.7\textwidth}}\lipsum[2]\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{p{1.5\textwidth}}\lipsum[2]\end{tabular}}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

The environment form automatically adds `\noindent`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, works like a charm. Had to upgrade my tex distro to get the package first, and then install some more ubuntu packages. `apt-cache search adjustbox` - and then I needed as well `apt-cache search collectbox` - are your friend.

Comment: Thanks egreg! This has a significant advantage over `resizebox{width}{height}{object}` in that it adjusts the `object`only if it needs to do so in order to fit the object on the page, whereas `resizebox` will adjust the object no matter what, resulting in small tables becoming awkwardly huge (unless there is a max width function that I am unaware of).

Comment: For tables I would suggest the `adjustbox` environment which also includes a `\noindent`. The `\adjustbox` macro actually also reads the content as a box and therefore works here just as fine, but the environment syntax is better suited IMHO.

Comment: you can also do: `\begin{adjustbox}{max height=8cm,max width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio}` which will scale the content inside those boundaries.

Comment: This scales the text = absolute crap.

Comment: @reggie I agree, but the customer's always right. `;-)`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a slightly different approach. The idea is to

1. put the `tabular` environment in a box
2. measure the box
3. if it's too wide then use `resizebox`
4. if it's not, then just display it

**example 1**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{mytabularwrap}{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}
  {\end{lrbox}%
  \setbox0\hbox{\usebox\mybox}%
  \ifdim\wd0<\textwidth
      \usebox\mybox%
  \else
      \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox\mybox}%
  \fi
  }
\begin{document}

hello world

\begin{mytabularwrap}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\end{mytabularwrap}

\noindent\begin{mytabularwrap}
  \begin{tabular}{*{30}c}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{tabular}
\end{mytabularwrap}
\end{document}
```

If you'd like it automated for every `tabular`, then you could use the [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox), the important lines are

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\begin{mytabularwrap}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{\end{mytabularwrap}}
```

**example 2**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{mytabularwrap}{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}
  {\end{lrbox}%
  \setbox0\hbox{\usebox\mybox}%
  \ifdim\wd0<\textwidth
      \usebox\mybox%
  \else
      \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox\mybox}%
  \fi
  }

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\begin{mytabularwrap}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{\end{mytabularwrap}}

\begin{document}

hello world

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4
\end{tabular}

\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{*{30}c}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For what it's worth, I would recommend against doing this for precisely the reasons that David Carlisle mentioned.

Comment: The line `\setbox0\hbox{\usebox\mybox}` which reboxes `\mybox` is useless. You can remove it and use `\ifdim\wd\mybox<\textwidth` instead of `\ifdim\wd0<\textwidth`.