# How to adjust a table to fit on page

Tags: tables, scaling, paper-size

I have the following latex table:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & X & MASHvstRap & MASHvsBEEML & tRapvsBEEML & frequency & Mash\_mean & BEEML\_mean & tRap\_mean \\ 
  \hline
1 & ETS & 8.95e-04 & 7.35e-04 & 4.78e-06 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.67 & 0.30 \\ 
  11 & ZnF\_C2H2 & 7.08e-21 & 2.09e-02 & 1.70e-26 &  54 & 0.55 & 0.64 & 0.25 \\ 
  10 & Zn2Cys6 & 4.94e-04 & 5.50e-02 & 3.52e-06 &  17 & 0.38 & 0.61 & 0.13 \\ 
  8 & IRF & 1.16e-06 & 6.65e-02 & 5.54e-08 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.62 & 0.28 \\ 
  2 & FH & 1.27e-05 & 8.61e-02 & 5.20e-07 &  10 & 0.53 & 0.66 & 0.27 \\ 
  3 & HLH & 2.49e-05 & 1.31e+00 & 4.27e-05 &  13 & 0.61 & 0.74 & 0.26 \\ 
  4 & HMG & 8.73e-33 & 1.41e+00 & 3.49e-08 &  44 & 0.55 & 0.48 & 0.12 \\ 
  12 & ZnF\_C4 & 2.92e-06 & 1.92e+00 & 1.03e-07 &  10 & 0.66 & 0.73 & 0.27 \\ 
  9 & unknown & 3.15e-27 & 1.96e+00 & 5.38e-21 & 121 & 0.44 & 0.49 & 0.16 \\ 
  5 & Homeo & 1.69e-164 & 6.26e+00 & 2.35e-75 & 158 & 0.72 & 0.73 & 0.17 \\ 
  7 & Homeo, POU & 3.12e-12 & 7.36e+00 & 5.21e-12 &  11 & 0.69 & 0.70 & 0.18 \\ 
  6 & Homeo  & 9.82e-13 & 9.73e+00 & 1.21e-05 &  19 & 0.67 & 0.65 & 0.14 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Paired t-test of most common TF families for Pearson Correlations} 
\end{table}
```

But unfortunately the table doesn't fit to normal a4 paper size, and therefore needs to be adjusted. I read a lot of questions of other Ops but cannot find out how to do this for my table.

I thought of using tabu{} or adjustbox{} but still did'nt manage to proper adjust my table.

Comment: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97505/2975 which I think should answer your question.

Comment: And: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. It's especially helpful if you post complete [minimal working examples (MWEs)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so we can see your basic document structure (class, packages etc.) as well.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I read the startes guide and code above is actually only code i have. rest is just standard. But with youre given example for my answer i did not manage to get a nice table.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer  Is there a simple fix for this, because i know am 5 hours further and tried everything only thing i get is errors errors and errors. And if it works it doesnt scale but adds some strange height and width next to my half table.

Comment: We are interested in this other "standard" stuff, too.

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw: Ok, I posted an answer now. Please comment on it if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If you're willing to just scale the entire table down, then this is fairly straight-forward, put it in a box and scale the box to `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
test

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & X & MASHvstRap & MASHvsBEEML & tRapvsBEEML & frequency & Mash\_mean & BEEML\_mean & tRap\_mean \\ 
  \hline
1 & ETS & 8.95e-04 & 7.35e-04 & 4.78e-06 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.67 & 0.30 \\ 
  11 & ZnF\_C2H2 & 7.08e-21 & 2.09e-02 & 1.70e-26 &  54 & 0.55 & 0.64 & 0.25 \\ 
  10 & Zn2Cys6 & 4.94e-04 & 5.50e-02 & 3.52e-06 &  17 & 0.38 & 0.61 & 0.13 \\ 
  8 & IRF & 1.16e-06 & 6.65e-02 & 5.54e-08 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.62 & 0.28 \\ 
  2 & FH & 1.27e-05 & 8.61e-02 & 5.20e-07 &  10 & 0.53 & 0.66 & 0.27 \\ 
  3 & HLH & 2.49e-05 & 1.31e+00 & 4.27e-05 &  13 & 0.61 & 0.74 & 0.26 \\ 
  4 & HMG & 8.73e-33 & 1.41e+00 & 3.49e-08 &  44 & 0.55 & 0.48 & 0.12 \\ 
  12 & ZnF\_C4 & 2.92e-06 & 1.92e+00 & 1.03e-07 &  10 & 0.66 & 0.73 & 0.27 \\ 
  9 & unknown & 3.15e-27 & 1.96e+00 & 5.38e-21 & 121 & 0.44 & 0.49 & 0.16 \\ 
  5 & Homeo & 1.69e-164 & 6.26e+00 & 2.35e-75 & 158 & 0.72 & 0.73 & 0.17 \\ 
  7 & Homeo, POU & 3.12e-12 & 7.36e+00 & 5.21e-12 &  11 & 0.69 & 0.70 & 0.18 \\ 
  6 & Homeo  & 9.82e-13 & 9.73e+00 & 1.21e-05 &  19 & 0.67 & 0.65 & 0.14 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Paired t-test of most common TF families for Pearson Correlations} 
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\resizebox` reads the whole table as marco argument which doesn't work with verbatim and some special TikZ matrix code. It's also not very efficient. An alternative would be to use the `adjustbox` package and replace the `\resizebox` with `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth} .. \end{adjustbox}`. Alternatively the `width` key can be replaced by `max width`, so that the table is only scaled down if needed. However, this is actually the accepted answer of the very similar question I linked in my comment above.

Comment: `\resizebox`will scale the contents of the third curly braces.  By having a `\tabular`with lots of columns if `l`, `c` and `r` will produce unpredictable results.  If you want to have a table of defined with and having its columns automatically adapted to that overall width, better use the `tabularx`-package and its `X`-column (capital X here!).

Comment: Give me your address to go there and give him a hug. :-)

Answer (score 59):

As already mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97506/2975 you can use `\resizebox` or better `adjustbox` to scale the table to a specific width, e.g. `\textwidth` which is the width of the text on the page. This however might make your table text very small and hard to read.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}% example text

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\small
\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & X & MASHvstRap & MASHvsBEEML & tRapvsBEEML & frequency & Mash\_mean & BEEML\_mean & tRap\_mean \\ 
  \hline
1 & ETS & 8.95e-04 & 7.35e-04 & 4.78e-06 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.67 & 0.30 \\ 
  11 & ZnF\_C2H2 & 7.08e-21 & 2.09e-02 & 1.70e-26 &  54 & 0.55 & 0.64 & 0.25 \\ 
  10 & Zn2Cys6 & 4.94e-04 & 5.50e-02 & 3.52e-06 &  17 & 0.38 & 0.61 & 0.13 \\ 
  8 & IRF & 1.16e-06 & 6.65e-02 & 5.54e-08 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.62 & 0.28 \\ 
  2 & FH & 1.27e-05 & 8.61e-02 & 5.20e-07 &  10 & 0.53 & 0.66 & 0.27 \\ 
  3 & HLH & 2.49e-05 & 1.31e+00 & 4.27e-05 &  13 & 0.61 & 0.74 & 0.26 \\ 
  4 & HMG & 8.73e-33 & 1.41e+00 & 3.49e-08 &  44 & 0.55 & 0.48 & 0.12 \\ 
  12 & ZnF\_C4 & 2.92e-06 & 1.92e+00 & 1.03e-07 &  10 & 0.66 & 0.73 & 0.27 \\ 
  9 & unknown & 3.15e-27 & 1.96e+00 & 5.38e-21 & 121 & 0.44 & 0.49 & 0.16 \\ 
  5 & Homeo & 1.69e-164 & 6.26e+00 & 2.35e-75 & 158 & 0.72 & 0.73 & 0.17 \\ 
  7 & Homeo, POU & 3.12e-12 & 7.36e+00 & 5.21e-12 &  11 & 0.69 & 0.70 & 0.18 \\ 
  6 & Homeo  & 9.82e-13 & 9.73e+00 & 1.21e-05 &  19 & 0.67 & 0.65 & 0.14 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Paired t-test of most common TF families for Pearson Correlations} 
\end{table} 

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

---

One way to increase your table is to make it actually wider than the text but still keep it centered as explained for figures in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16584/2975. This can be easily done by using `\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.2\textwidth,center=\textwidth} .. \end{adjustbox}` instead of the keys used above. This values will make the table 120% of the text width but keep it centered to the text.

[image: result 2]

---

If this is still not suitable for you, you could rotate the `tabular` and `\caption` using the `angle=90` key of adjustbox. Also sometimes it is advisable to break complicated tables into several smaller ones, which is of course not always possible.

Comment: Is it better to use this than, say, `tabulary` package?

Comment: @MarioS.E.: This depends really on the table content. AFAIK `tabularx` or `tabulary` only helps if you have longer text in at least one cell which then can be broken to fit into the rest of the line width. In this example it's not really useful because their are only numbers and single words. Ok, the headlines could be shorten or set smaller, but I wouldn't do this with `tabulary` but manually using two rows or something like `\stackbox`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I dont want to bother you all the time, but the package is installed, and only cant be loaded. Still thanks for the lead to other article but wont help me because adjustbox is already installed