# error '\clipbox already defined' when use package adjustbox

Tags: package-options, adjustbox

I am trying draw table. I use adjustbox package. I loaded this package in separate file. That separate file contains the packages I use.

```
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{Files/bibspacing}
\usepackage[round, sort&compress, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{6pt}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{verbatim}   % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}           %(for text and formulas)
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
```

Below is the code I use to draw my table.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\label{tbl:jadualS1} % is used to refer this table in the text
\caption{Values for dihedral angles.}
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c} % centered columns (4 columns)
\toprule 

  & $\Phi$(H1-C1-O1-C4') & $\Psi$(C1-O1-C4'-H4') & & Ref    \\

 \midrule

malto & -36.0 & -49.0 & - & \cite{Ott1996}  \\
cello &  48.0 & -25.0 & - & \cite{Ham1970}  \\
 & $\Phi$(O5-C1-O1-C6') & $\Psi$(C1-O1-C6'-C5') & $\Omega$(O1-C6'-C5'-C4') & \\
isomal & -49.2 & 167.3 & -45.3 & \cite{Jeffrey1991} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

When I compile I get error message as "**Command \clipbox already defined. }**"

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Please reedit your question to contain a self contained example we can copy an run our self. (1) There is no indication of documentclass, (2) surely not all those packages are relevant for this problem. BTW: the process to preparing a truly minimal example often ends up giving the answer to the error, so it is a valuable lesson

Comment: BTW2: generally it is better to redesign a table, than to scale it, and (3) You have placed the `\label` in the wrong place, it goes *after* `\caption`.

Comment: dopn't load epsfig package

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pstricks` defines a `\clipbox` command which clashes with `adjustbox` you can arrange to avoid that, but do you really need to load all those packages? it looks like there are lots of packages loaded that you do not need. `epsfig` should never be loaded, `fixltx2e` should always be loaded first you reference it twice, neither at the beginning, you load `inputenc` without specifying an encoding, so it does nothing useful.

So your best course of action is to delete every `\usepackage` that you do not use in the document, then see if you still have a clash.

If you do then if you add

```
\let\clipbox\relax
```

after loading `pstricks` it will be undefined when you later load `adjustbox`. But only do this if you really need both packages.

In particular scaling text such as

```
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{
```

almost always produces a typographically poor result as it produces inconsistent font sizes.

You don't enlarge the text in a normal paragraph to make it stretch to the page size, so why do that for text that happens to be in a table?

Comment: #David Carlisle, I found out the packages pstricks, pst-grad, and pst-plot giving the error. Thanks for the indication. Well I am use those packages for some special characters. I use  \let\clipbox\relax after pstricks and associated packages. Now the compilation running fine. I use the ajustbox package to fit my table into a page and I get the info from (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121155/how-to-adjust-a-table-to-fit-on-page). Thanks for all.