# Lyx not showing all content when converting to pdf

Tags: lyx, pdf

long story short I want the lyx to show the whole table when converting to pdf

[image: image description]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your table is too large to fit the page, see if this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121155/how-to-adjust-a-table-to-fit-on-page?noredirect=1&lq=1 could help you.

Comment: A compilation of approaches to improve such a situation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: I was thinking something like moving the entire page to the left or the PDF is the same as i see it in lyx which is perfect