# Fit table to page

Tags: tables, scaling

I am new to latex and struggling a bit to fit a regression table onto one page (portrait). At the moment I am using `\resizebox` but cannot quite get it work. I found a similar thread which relies on the `adjustbox` package but my PC cannot install it for some reason... ([Shrink table to fit on a page, or keep it as it is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97505/shrink-table-to-fit-on-a-page-or-keep-it-as-it-is))

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can shrink the table to fit on one page?

Here is my setup:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amsthm,lscape,setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.85in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.46}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\flushbottom

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25} \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccc}
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Table 5.1.  \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\scriptsize{Notes text......}} \\
\cline{1-6}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A}\\
\cline{1-6}
{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Purchase Turnover} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sale Turnover}\\
\cline{2-3}  \cline{5-6}
{} & {$(1)$} & {$(2)$} & & {$(1)$} & {$(2)$} \\ 
\cline{1-6}
Experience & -0.148 & -0.0114 &       & -0.0025 & 0.0058 \\
  & (-39.87) & (-4.10) &       & (-1.37) & (2.41) \\
Initial Dependent &       & 0.0857 &       &       & 0.110 \\
  &       & (15.02) &       &       & (7.02)  \\
Lag Dependent &       & 0.126 &       &       & 0.125 \\
  &       & (12.11) &       &       & (9.74)  \\
Lag Return &       & 0.0483 &       &       & 0.0295$ \\
  &       & (7.14) &       &       & (5.01) \\
Intercept & 0.350 & 0.245 &       & 0.0634 & -0.121 \\
  & (50.57) & (2.88) &       & (19.78) & (-1.64) \\
\cline{1-6}
Controls & No & Yes & & No & Yes \\
Year FE & Yes & Yes & & Yes & Yes \\
County FE & Yes & Yes & & Yes & Yes \\
\cline{1-6}
No. Obs. & 129,861 & 84,747 &       & 129,861 & 84,747 \\
Adj. R-sq & 0.128 & 0.075 &       & 0.017 & 0.050 \\
\cline{1-6}
% Panel B
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B - All Households}\\
\cline{1-6}
{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Purchase Turnover} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sale Turnover}  \\
\cline{2-3}  \cline{5-6}
{} & {$(1)$} & {$(2)$} & & {$(1)$} & {$(2)$} \\ 
\cline{1-6}
Experience & -0.121 & -0.0004 &       & -0.078 & 0.041 \\
  & (-48.57) & (-2.50) &       & (-1.77) & (2.03) \\
Initial Dependent &       & 0.0997 &       &       & 0.250 \\
  &       & (19.92) &       &       & (7.96)  \\
Lag Dependent &       & 0.116 &       &       & 0.144 \\
  &       & (11.00) &       &       & (7.28)  \\
Lag Return &       & 0.323 &       &       & 0.0258 \\
  &       & (4.58) &       &       & (2.31) \\
Intercept & 0.589 & 0.225 &       & 0.0436 & -0.122 \\
  & (51.57) & (2.11) &       & (15.72) & (-1.51) \\
\cline{1-6}
Controls & No & Yes & & No & Yes  \\
Year FE & Yes & Yes & & Yes & Yes  \\
County FE & Yes & Yes & & Yes & Yes \\
\cline{1-6}
No. Obs. & 1,256,615 & 874,015 &       & 1,256,615 & 874,015 \\
Adj. R-sq & 0.017 & 0.045 &       & 0.007 & 0.026 \\
\cline{1-6}
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{center}
```

Sorry for such long code! Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following changes in your code:

- If I correctly understand you'd like to have a table of the same width as the text width. This is simply achievable by using `tabularx`. For this don't use `adjustbox`, because the table will become very ugly.
- the table caption, except for `longtable` should be outside of `tabular` environment, so I introduced floating environment `table` and added the `caption` package
- For nice looking tables it is appropriate to use the `booktabs` packages and its rules: `toprule`, `midrule` ... as you can see in code below
- Your table actually has five columns, not six, so I reduces number of columns
- with `showframe` I show that table has a width of text width. For actual use, please remove this package.
- It seems that in the main text and the table text you would like to have different interline spaces. For this I use the package `setspace` and put the complete table content between `\begin{spacing}{1.0}`  ... `\end{spacing}`. You can change this stretch to your wish and taste.

After all these changes I obtain the following:

[image]

I didn't retype entire table, missing rows are easy to add.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{endnotes}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{verbatim}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.85in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.46}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\flushbottom

    \usepackage{showframe}% just to show page layout
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}
    \begin{spacing}{1.0}
\caption[Table 5.1]
        {Table 5.1.\medskip\newline
        Notes text......}
\label{tab:mytable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{l*{4}{C}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Panel A}\\
    \midrule
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Purchase Turnover} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sale Turnover}\\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}  \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    & $(1)$     &  $(2)$    & $(1)$     & $(2)$     \\
    \midrule
Experience 
    & -0.148    & -0.0114   & -0.0025   &   0.0058  \\
    & (-39.87)  & (-4.10)   & (-1.37)   &   (2.41)  \\
Initial Dependent 
    &           & 0.0857    &           &   0.110   \\
    &           & (15.02)   &           &   (7.02)  \\
Lag Dependent 
    &           & 0.126     &           &   0.125   \\
    &           & (12.11)   &           &   (9.74)  \\
Lag Return 
    &           & 0.0483    &           &   0.0295  \\
    &           &           &           &   (5.01)  \\
Intercept 
    &   0.350   & 0.245     &   0.0634  &    -0.121 \\
    &   (50.57) & (2.88)    &   (19.78) &   (-1.64) \\
    \midrule
Controls 
    & No        &   Yes     &   No      &   Yes     \\
Year FE 
    &   Yes     &   Yes     &   Yes     &   Yes     \\
County FE   
    & Yes       &   Yes     &   Yes     &   Yes     \\
    \midrule
No. Obs. 
    & 129,861   & 84,747    &   129,861 & 84,747    \\
Adj. R-sq 
    & 0.128     & 0.075     &   0.017   & 0.050     \\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace[1em]
% Panel B
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Panel B - All Households}    \\
    \midrule
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Purchase Turnover} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sale Turnover}       \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}  \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    & $(1)$     &  $(2)$    & $(1)$     & $(2)$     \\
    \midrule
Experience 
    & -0.121    & -0.0004   &   -0.078  &   0.041   \\
    & (-48.57)  & (-2.50)   &   (-1.77) &   (2.03)  \\
Initial Dependent 
    &           & 0.0997    &           &   0.250   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{spacing}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like the code below?

(Your code didn't compile: missing curlies, $ instead of \$.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amsthm,lscape,setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.85in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.46}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\flushbottom

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{4.5in}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccc}
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Table 5.1.}  \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\scriptsize{Notes text......}} \\
\cline{1-6}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A}\\
\cline{1-6}
{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Purchase Turnover} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sale Turnover}\\
\cline{2-3}  \cline{5-6}
{} & {$(1)$} & {$(2)$} & & {$(1)$} & {$(2)$} \\ 
\cline{1-6}
Experience & -0.148 & -0.0114 &       & -0.0025 & 0.0058 \\
  & (-39.87) & (-4.10) &       & (-1.37) & (2.41) \\
Initial Dependent &       & 0.0857 &       &       & 0.110 \\
  &       & (15.02) &       &       & (7.02)  \\
Lag Dependent &       & 0.126 &       &       & 0.125 \\
  &       & (12.11) &       &       & (9.74)  \\
Lag Return &       & 0.0483 &       &       & 0.0295 \\
  &       & (7.14) &       &       & (5.01) \\
Intercept & 0.350 & 0.245 &       & 0.0634 & -0.121 \\
  & (50.57) & (2.88) &       & (19.78) & (-1.64) \\
\cline{1-6}
Controls & No & Yes & & No & Yes \\
Year FE & Yes & Yes & & Yes & Yes \\
County FE & Yes & Yes & & Yes & Yes \\
\cline{1-6}
No. Obs. & 129,861 & 84,747 &       & 129,861 & 84,747 \\
Adj. R-sq & 0.128 & 0.075 &       & 0.017 & 0.050 \\
\cline{1-6}
% Panel B
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B - All Households}\\
\cline{1-6}
{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Purchase Turnover} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sale Turnover}  \\
\cline{2-3}  \cline{5-6}
{} & {$(1)$} & {$(2)$} & & {$(1)$} & {$(2)$} \\ 
\cline{1-6}
Experience & -0.121 & -0.0004 &       & -0.078 & 0.041 \\
  & (-48.57) & (-2.50) &       & (-1.77) & (2.03) \\
Initial Dependent &       & 0.0997 &       &       & 0.250 \\
  &       & (19.92) &       &       & (7.96)  \\
Lag Dependent &       & 0.116 &       &       & 0.144 \\
  &       & (11.00) &       &       & (7.28)  \\
Lag Return &       & 0.323 &       &       & 0.0258 \\
  &       & (4.58) &       &       & (2.31) \\
Intercept & 0.589 & 0.225 &       & 0.0436 & -0.122 \\
  & (51.57) & (2.11) &       & (15.72) & (-1.51) \\
\cline{1-6}
Controls & No & Yes & & No & Yes  \\
Year FE & Yes & Yes & & Yes & Yes  \\
County FE & Yes & Yes & & Yes & Yes \\
\cline{1-6}
No. Obs. & 1,256,615 & 874,015 &       & 1,256,615 & 874,015 \\
Adj. R-sq & 0.017 & 0.045 &       & 0.007 & 0.026 \\
\cline{1-6}
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{center}

\end{document}


[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```