# Table is out of range

Tags: tables

My doc is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\textbf{Хід роботи}\end{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{№ Досліду} & \multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Результати досліду} & \multicolumn{6}{ |c| }{Розраховані величини} \\
\cline{2-11}
& $E$, В & $I$, мА & $U_0$, В & $U_1$, В & $R_0$ & $R_1$ & $P$ & $P_0$ & $P_1$ & К.к.д \% \\
\hline
1.$r_1 = 0$ & 12 & 4.000 & 12 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 0 & 0 \\
2.$r_1 = r_0 / 2$ & 12 & 2.666 & 8 & 4 & 3 & 1.5 & 31.984002 & 21.322668 & 10.661334 & 33
\\
3.$r_1 = r_0$ \\
4.$r_1 = 2r_0$ \\
5.$r_1 = 3r_0$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You have posted your code, but what exactly is your question? Perhaps you would be interested in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97505/shrink-table-to-fit-on-a-page-or-keep-it-as-it-is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the inter-column space a bit, e.g. to `\tabcolsep=2.5pt`. Below I have included the package `showframe` to mark the border of the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\textbf{Хід роботи}\end{center}
{\tabcolsep=2.5pt%
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{№ Досліду} & \multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Результати досліду} & \multicolumn{6}{ |c| }{Розраховані величини} \\
\cline{2-11}
& $E$, В & $I$, мА & $U_0$, В & $U_1$, В & $R_0$ & $R_1$ & $P$ & $P_0$ & $P_1$ & К.к.д \% \\
\hline
1.$r_1 = 0$ & 12 & 4.000 & 12 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 0 & 0 \\
2.$r_1 = r_0 / 2$ & 12 & 2.666 & 8 & 4 & 3 & 1.5 & 31.984002 & 21.322668 & 10.661334 & 33
\\
3.$r_1 = r_0$ \\
4.$r_1 = 2r_0$ \\
5.$r_1 = 3r_0$
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: All of my doc is in border now, and it's bad for me.

Comment: Oh, I understated, must remove `\usepackage{showframe}`

Comment: Another possible recommendation would be to round the numbers in the P, P_0, and P_1 columns to 3 digits after the decimal marker.