# scaling latex objects

Tags: scaling

Imagine that I have a wide table that does not fit into page:

```
\begin{tabular}
Some very wide table
\end{tabular}
```

Can I scale this object without recurring to adjusting the font size?

Comment: Changing the font size is better than scaling, as this will use appropriate letter shapes and thus be better readable, see also this comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97505/shrink-table-to-fit-on-a-page-or-keep-it-as-it-is#comment209757_97505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}    

\begin{document}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b \\ 
\hline 
c & d \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
}

\resizebox{2cm}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b \\ 
\hline 
c & d \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you supply the height or width? What does `!` stand for?

Comment: @Viesturs You can look here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables `\resizebox{width}{height}{object}` The `!` mean that scale height anong with the width.