# Scaling listings in beamer

Tags: scaling

This answer 
[scaling latex objects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414913/scaling-latex-objects)
advises to use `\resizebox` to scale Latex objects.

However, this approach fails when rescaling a listing in beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%                                                                                                                                                                               
    \begin{lstlisting}
      some -program --code "Not fitting into page"
    \end{lstlisting}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The error one gets is

```
! Argument of \lst@next has an extra }.
```

How to scale a listing in beamer?

Comment: The scaling would fail in any other documentclass as well, since you're using a verbatim environment like `lstlisting` inside of a macro -- that is not possible.

Comment: Please do not scale elements which contain text, this will give suboptimal results!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the comment you cannot pass verbatim stuff as arguments to a macro. But for `listings` you can easily change the font size.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{lstlisting}
some -program --code "Not fitting into page"
  \end{lstlisting}
  \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\small]
some -program --code "Not fitting into page"
  \end{lstlisting}
  \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\footnotesize]
some -program --code "Not fitting into page"
  \end{lstlisting}
  \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont]
some -program --code "Not fitting into page"
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

If you want to change it for the document or a complete frame you can use `lstset`.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \lstset{basicstyle=\small}
  \begin{lstlisting}
some -program --code "Not fitting into page"
  \end{lstlisting}
  \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\normalsize]
some -program --code "Not fitting into page"
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
```

[image]