# Listing too wide for colour box

Tags: listings

I have the LaTeX code below to represent listings of C++ code, however the C++ code seems to be too wide for the greyed out box in the background. I would also like the listing too fit as it was formatted by the creator of the code.

```
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\lstset{
backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,    
%   rulecolor=,
    language=[GNU]C++,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize,
        upquote=true,
        aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
        columns=fixed,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=false,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=single,
        numbers=left,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.026,0.112,0.095},
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
        numberstyle=\color[rgb]{0.205, 0.142, 0.73},
%        \lstdefinestyle{C++}{language=C++,style=numbers}’.
}
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,
  language=C++,
  captionpos=b,
  tabsize=3,
  frame=lines,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
%  identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
  keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
  commentstyle=\color{Darkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{red}
  }
```

Which gives the image below:

[image]

I would prefer if the green hyphens and any other symbols extending into the next line be one neat line as it is in the source file from OpenFOAM.

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to fix the issue. \
Did some searching and found this thread
[Scaling listings in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415042/scaling-listings-in-beamer)

Used the following code when placing my listing 
`\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont]` 
and now everything fits within the borders nicely. 
Hope it holds for the other files as well.