# "Missing \endgroup inserted" with tabular - possible mismatch with adjustbox?

Tags: tables, adjustbox, stata

I am writing a document for which I need to insert tables produced by the statistical progam `Stata`. More specifically I am using `Stata` package `outreg2`. Here is an example of the type of a table that I am trying to insert:

```
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \hline
 & (1) & (2) \\
VARIABLES & mpg & mpg \\ \hline
 &  &  \\
foreign & -1.967 & -1.655 \\
 & (1.181) & (1.082) \\
weight & -0.00420** & -0.00647*** \\
 & (0.00202) & (0.000700) \\
headroom & -0.0592 & -0.219 \\
 & (0.645) & (0.542) \\
trunk & -0.0122 &  \\
 & (0.159) &  \\
length & -0.0631 &  \\
 & (0.0644) &  \\
turn & -0.165 &  \\
 & (0.198) &  \\
displacement & 0.000792 &  \\
 & (0.0103) &  \\
Constant & 53.14*** & 41.99*** \\
 & (7.584) & (2.312) \\
 &  &  \\
Observations & 74 & 74 \\
 R-squared & 0.677 & 0.663 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{ Standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}
```

You can replicate the table in `Stata` by:

```
sysuse auto,clear
    regress mpg foreign weight headroom trunk length turn displacement
    outreg2 using myfile, replace tex(frag)
    regress mpg foreign weight headroom
    outreg2 using myfile, tex(frag)
```

I made a new tex command for inserting the table:

```
\newcommand{\stataTable}[3]{
  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{#2}
      \noindent\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
        \input{#1}}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \small
      \item #3
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
}
```

It takes the input file, caption and an endnote as arguments. Now I try to add the table in the document by:

```
\stataTable{myfile.tex}{OLS estimates.}{\lipsum}
```

I do this with `threeparttable` package, because I need to add notes in the end of the table.

Unfortunately this does not work, and I get the error `Missing \endgroup inserted...`. I understand that a missing curly bracket is a possible reason, but I just can't figure out where that could be.

However, I can make this work with an alternative command that does not adjust the table width:

```
\newcommand{\stataTable}[3]{
  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{#2}
      \input{#1}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \small
      \item #3
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
}
```

So it seems that by trying to adjust the width of the table, I am breaking the function somehow. I have also tried an alternative way (`\mytabularwrap`) to adjust the width presented here:

[Shrink table to fit on a page, or keep it as it is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97505/shrink-table-to-fit-on-a-page-or-keep-it-as-it-is/97534#97534)

That did not work either. Nevertheless, the table width needs to be adjusted to the text width.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: scaling tables should only be done as a last resort (and even then don't do it) you would not justify text in a paragraph by using arbitrary font sizes by scaling lines to fit, so why inflict this on tables?

Comment: Well I just want the table to fit in the page.

Comment: yes as I say you also want normal text to fit to the page but not at the price of distorting all the text.