# Table out of margin?

Tags: tables, margins

This is my code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|l|lll|llll|l|}
\hline
\multirow{}{}{Algorithm Name} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Statistical properties}                               & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Algorithm's features}                                                                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Notes}     \\ \cline{2-8}
                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Average} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Variance} & Covariance & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Non-Blind} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Noise robustness} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Linear algorithm} & CDW &                            \\ \hline
Algorithm1: Simple algorithm    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F}        & F          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F}                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T}                & F   & Illustrative purposes only \\ \hline
Algorithm2: Sebe 2005 {[}29{]}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T}        & F          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T}                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F}                & T   & None                       \\ \hline
Algorithm3: Sebe 2006 {[}30{]}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T}        & T          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T}                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F}                & T   & Future work                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I want it to be like the following that I have made with Word : [image: this one]

Any help is really appreciated !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shrink table to fit on a page, or keep it as it is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97505/shrink-table-to-fit-on-a-page-or-keep-it-as-it-is)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It works, but the  font is too small !

Comment: @user187803 I have edited my question

Comment: @M-S It is clearer now, but your document is far from [minimal](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/73317) and doesn't compile without errors. Please fix these problems so as to make it easy for other people to help you.

Answer (score 4):

For your problem exist many solution, for example use `p<width>` columns, use `X` columns defined in `tabularx` package, etc. In your case may be handy `tabularray` package. Anyway, your columns headers are quite wide, even if they are written in two columns. A remedy can be make text area a bit wider (by use of the `geometry` package) and use the `\footnotesize` font:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec= { X[1.4,l,m] *{7}{X[c,m]} X[c, m]},
             colsep = 3pt,
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
 \SetCell[r=2]{m}  {Algorithm\\ Name}
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {Statistical properties}
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}  {Algorithm's features}                                                                               
                    &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{m}  Notes     \\
    &   Average
        &   Variance
            &   Co\-variance 
                &   {Non-\\ Blind}
                    &   Noise robustness
                        &   Linear algorithm
                            & CDW 
                                &                               \\
{Algorithm 1:\\ Simple algorithm}   
    & T & F & F & T & F & T & F & Illustrative purposes only    \\
Algorithm 2: Sebe 2005 [29]  
    & T & T & F & F & T & F & T & None                          \\
Algorithm 3: Sebe 2006 {[}30{]}  
    & T & T & T & F & T & F & T & Future work                   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you for some reason had not have wider `\textwidth` you can make wider only locally for table by help of the package `changepage`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow automatic line breaks in most of the table's columns. This may be done by switching from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment and employing `X`-type columns where needed. I would further like to encourage you to give the table a much more open look by (a) getting rid of all vertical rules and (b) employing fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules, using the macros of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L CCC CCCc L @{}}
\toprule
Algorithm Name & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Statistical properties}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Algorithm's features} & Notes \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-8}
& Average & Variance & Covariance & Non-Blind & Noise robustness & Linear algorithm & CDW & \\ 
\midrule
Alg1: Simple algorithm & T & F & F & T & F & T & F & Illustrative purposes only \\ 
\addlinespace
Alg2: Sebe 2005 [29]   & T & T & F & F & T & F & T & None \\ 
\addlinespace
Alg3: Sebe 2006 [30]   & T & T & T & F & T & F & T & Future work \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```