\usepackage{array} causes my build to break
I'm trying to add the following lines to my document:
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

as per How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft? to center my table boxes.
However, just adding the line \usepackage{array}  causes my build to break with a "Undefined control sequence. }" on this command:
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Sec.} 

and also same error on this table:
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{cl|lll|}
            \cline{3-5}
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                &           & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Counts on:}                             \\ \cline{3-5} 
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                &           & CT\_PMTOR           & CT\_SiOR          & CT\_SiAND         \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Relative to:}} & CT\_PMTOR & 100.00 $\pm$   0.19 & 713.36 $\pm$ 1.05 & 139.53 $\pm$ 0.25 \\
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                              & CT\_SiOR  & 14.02 $\pm$ 0.02    & 100.00 $\pm$ 0.07 & 19.56 $\pm$ 0.02  \\
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                              & CT\_SiAND & 71.67 $\pm$ 0.13    & 511.25 $\pm$ 0.65 & 100.00 $\pm$ 0.16 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:table}
\end{table}

BUT NOT this table, which is apparantly fine:
    \begin{table}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \noindent\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
            \begin{tabular}{cccc|c} 
                \toprule
                Channel & Background Rate & Total counts & Background Subtracted Counts & Simulated Counts   \\
                \midrule
                CT\_PMTOR & 8.52 $\pm$ 0.015Hz   & 530818 $\pm$ 729   & 530443 $\pm$ 729 & X   \\   
                CT\_SiOR & 25.58 $\pm$ 0.026Hz   & 3785118 $\pm$ 1946 & 3783992 $\pm$ 1946 & X \\
                CT\_SiAND & 0.297 $\pm$ 0.0028Hz & 740160 $\pm$ 860  & 740147 $\pm$ 860 & X    \\
                \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}
        \caption{}
        \label{tab:text}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

Anyone got any idea whats going on here?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{arydshln} % add hash line for tables

\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{cl|lll|}
                \cline{3-5}
                \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Counts on:} \\
                \cline{3-5} 
                \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & & CT\_PMTOR & CT\_SiOR & CT\_SiAND \\
                \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Relative to:}} & CT\_PMTOR & 100.00 $\pm$ 0.19 & 713.36 $\pm$ 1.05 & 139.53 $\pm$ 0.25 \\
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & CT\_SiOR & 14.02 $\pm$ 0.02 & 100.00 $\pm$ 0.07 & 19.56 $\pm$ 0.02 \\
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & CT\_SiAND & 71.67 $\pm$ 0.13 & 511.25 $\pm$ 0.65 & 100.00 $\pm$ 0.16 \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}%
        }
        \caption{Caption for Table 1}
        \label{tab:table}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        \adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
            \begin{tabular}{cccc|c} 
                \toprule
                Channel & Background Rate & Total counts & Background Subtracted Counts & Simulated Counts \\
                \midrule
                CT\_PMTOR & 8.52 $\pm$ 0.015 Hz & 530818 $\pm$ 729 & 530443 $\pm$ 729 & X \\   
                CT\_SiOR & 25.58 $\pm$ 0.026 Hz & 3785118 $\pm$ 1946 & 3783992 $\pm$ 1946 & X \\
                CT\_SiAND & 0.297 $\pm$ 0.0028 Hz & 740160 $\pm$ 860 & 740147 $\pm$ 860 & X \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        }
        \caption{Caption for Table 2}
        \label{tab:text}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}

Comment out and re-add the array package to break/fix the build

Actually even if I comment out the line that "causes" the error, i still get an error on the same line with undefined control seq....?

Please post a complete minimal working example which reproduces the issue. Right now we can only offer guesses.

Please provide the error message from your log verbatim. The line breaks of such error messages have a meaning.

Unrelated: You should never use \adjustbox or \resizebox or anything like that on a table. This leads to inconsistent line widths and text sizes. To reduce the size of your table use \small or similar, reduce the column space, etc. But don't scale it.

Scaling elements which contain text is usually a bad idea.

It appears to be the \usepackage{arydshln} line that breaks it.... Not sure why. Also didn't know about the resizebox  on a table issue, what is the issue with this? Is there a better way? All my tables have this aroud them

Added MWE by the way

array must be loaded before arydshln.

Echt... well thats the solution I guess... Can you also advise then how to keep tables within text width without resizebox?

This one says to use it on tables: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97505/shrink-table-to-fit-on-a-page-or-keep-it-as-it-is

@lukygee Use a suitable font size or change the layout of your table. If you just scale your table to fit the text width, your document will look like a ransom letter.

@lukygee - You've misunderstood the point of the posting you've provided a link to. Just because something is possible in no way implies that it is a good idea to go down that route. For instance, I can "forget" my wedding anniversary day, but my spouse is almost certainly not going to be pleased...

@lukygee Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332903/36296

Even that link says to use it:
"For just-too-wide tabulars, you can resize the entire table to fit within your bounds horizontally using \resizebox{}{}{} where  is at most \linewidth or \textwidth (see Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize). The notation ! for  will ensure that the aspect ratio of the resizing is kept."
So the alternatives to \resizebox as according to the link provided by
samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz is to remove content, remove spacing, or resizebox?

Even without that there is a further point here you seem to make is that the only way to make a document not "look like a ransom letter" is to have every table match the font size of the smallest font of all tables? Is this correct?

Given the MWE how would you make them both fit without looking like a ransom letter? One is clearly larger, so just make the smaller table match the font size of the larger one?

Another point, @Skillmon, you say don't use \adjustbox or \resizebox because it results in inconsistant text sizes, but then also say use \small [to adjust the text sizes] instead? How are these any different? I don't quite understand what you guys are trying to keep consistant when you say this, do you believe that all fonts in a document should be the same size? If so \small also does not work. In fact, if all text in a document must be the same size, then all text in the document must be the size of the font of your widest table?

@lukygee You don't need to match the font size of all tables. However you need to pick a harmonic and limited set set of differentiable font sizes you use in your document. One such set is normally provided by your class with \normalsize, \small,  \footnotesize etc. They are designed to work together.

Your second table wastes a lot of space. You could use shorter headings or make them in two lines. Instead of using the +- notation, put the uncertainty in parentheses to make the notation more compact and take into account significant figures.

Unrelated to your space problems, but have a look at the siunitx package to properly align the numbers and get rid of all your vertical lines.

Pretty much what @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz says. It's about having a consistent harmonic set, not all sizes ever imaginable. Also, for good fonts the glyphs of different font sizes are actually not the same if scaled to the same size, which usually results in better ligibility. Also, it's not only about the font sizes, but also your rule thicknesses.

You need to load array before arydshln.
But you can also improve the appearance of your tables: the second one needs to be reduced in width, but not by resizing it; rather, you want to avoid repetitions.
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln} % add hash line for tables



\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\sisetup{uncertainty-mode=separate}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=3.2(2)]
  S[table-format=3.2(2)]
  S[table-format=3.2(2)]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Relative to & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Counts on} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& {CT\_PMTOR} & {CT\_SiOR} & {CT\_SiAND} \\
\midrule
CT\_PMTOR & 100.00 \pm 0.19 & 713.36 \pm 1.05 & 139.53 \pm 0.25 \\
CT\_SiOR  &  14.02 \pm 0.02 & 100.00 \pm 0.07 &  19.56 \pm 0.02 \\
CT\_SiAND &  71.67 \pm 0.13 & 511.25 \pm 0.65 & 100.00 \pm 0.16 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption for Table 1}
\label{tab:table}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1.5pt}% 11.87808/8

\newcommand{\hd}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=2.3]
  @{${}\pm{}$}
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  @{${}\pm{}$}
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  @{${}\pm{}$}
  S[table-format=4.0]
  c
  @{}
} 
\toprule
Channel &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\smash{\hd{Background \\ Rate (Hz)}}} &
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Counts} \\
\cmidrule(l){4-8}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Total} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\hd{Background \\ Subtracted}} &
Simulated \\
\midrule
CT\_PMTOR & 8.52 & 0.015 & 530818 & 729 & 530443 & 729 & X \\   
CT\_SiOR  & 25.58 & 0.026 & 3785118 & 1946 & 3783992 & 1946 & X \\
CT\_SiAND & 0.297 & 0.0028 & 740160 & 860 & 740147 & 860 & X \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption for Table 2}
\label{tab:text}

\end{table}
    
\end{document}

For the second table, I looked at the overfull box message and divided the amount between the eight available intercolumn spaces. For your setup, comment the \addtolength line and look at the amount you get, which depends on the actual settings of your document.
After seeing the amount of overfull, if any, just divide by 8.


There is an extra ± in the second column of the last tabular.

@F.Pantigny Oops! Fixed.

Okay I will admit your tables look better.... Can you explain what the {   @{}   l   S[table-format=2.3]   @{${}\pm{}$}   S[table-format=1.4]   S[table-format=7.0]   @{${}\pm{}$}   S[table-format=4.0]   S[table-format=7.0]   @{${}\pm{}$}   S[table-format=4.0]   c   @{} }  lines are doing (I know they are setting the format), I am a little confused on how they are working/what they are doing?

@lukygee They're features of the siunitx package: you can find them in the manual for the package. For the second table I had to resort to a different scheme than the first, because the “plus-minus“ parts aren't actually “uncertainty”; the bit @{${}\pm{}$} inserts the symbol between columns.

Why do you say the plus-minus is not uncertainty for the second table? because the digits dont match up? ie they should be: 0.1234 +/- 0.0014 instead of 0.12 +/- 0.0014? If so this is an error, as these are placeholder numbers

@lukygee They're not uncertainties in the sense of siunitx, because they're not “uniform” across the column.

You report an undefined control sequence error message on this line:
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Sec.}

To the best of my knowledge, the only LaTeX package that defines a macro called \subsectionautorefname is hyperref. The error message, then, indicates that your document has failed to load hyperref. Note that as long as hyperref is not loaded, this error message will be generated whether or not the array package is loaded.
The MWE you've posted in the meantime reveals that you load the arydshln package. As @campa has already pointed out in a comment, array must be loaded before arydshln.
