# Automatic width setting in LyX

Tags: graphics, lyx, dimensions

Is there any preference setting so that LyX automatically adjusts images width to `\linewidth` when they are added, instead of doing so by hand whenever a new image is inserted?
[image: Setting I want to be adjusted automatically, adjusted manually in this cap.]

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted, thank you very much @Werner!

Comment: Also consider using graphics groups. See Help > User Guide, Section 4.4.2 Grouping of Image Settings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the keys associated with `\includegraphics` globally in your LaTeX Preamble by adding to it

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
```

This will resize *all* images (either enlarging *or* shrinking) to make them fit to `\linewidth`. If you only wish to shrink image that are too large, you can use (from [Resize images to half of text width only if too big for page margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96408/5764)):

```
\makeatletter
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
  \linewidth
\else
  \Gin@nat@width
\fi}
\makeatother
```

Here `\Gin@nat@width` is the natural width of the image to be included.

Comment: This works perfectly if there are figure floats, otherwise causes latex to crash. How can I put this in an if statement such that
`if there is at least a figure float
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
else
do nothing
\fi`

Comment: @BerkerPeköz: That should not be the case. No figure floats typically mean no `\includegraphics` and therefore no use of the `Gin` family of keys. One can test for the number of `figure`s, say, in a document, but that should not be necessary here. Perhaps you can show your code to identify where you may be going wrong...?

Comment: thanks for your quick response after all these years :)  A simple MWE would be `\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{document}
 This is a MWE
\end{document}`
If a figure float is present, the command runs beautifully but if not, it causes pdflatex to crash. I've been commenting it out when there is no figure and enable it as I add one, but I'm trying to automate this process with an if statement.

Comment: @BerkerPeköz: Ahhh. LyX inserts the use of the [`graphicx` package](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) if there are images included in the document, but otherwise removes it. Just add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble before the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` addition I specify in the answer.

Comment: now it's robust to not having figures, and the solution is simple and beautiful it doesn't even need if statements. thank you so much :)

Comment: For those, like I, who do not speak latex, note that \maketletter needs to be \makeatletter.  (I can't edit it because its only a one character change and stackexchange doesn't feel that merits an edit.  Go figure.)