# How do I set a max-width on images?

Tags: graphics

In my document I have a lot of images. Some are small icons and others are massive screenshots. The images should display either

1. Their full resolution if the image is smaller than the width of the
   document, or
2. Scaled down to the width of the document itself if the
   image is larger.

Right now each image is scaled to the width of the document regardless of how big the original image is. This means that the smaller images are blown up and pixelated, but the larger images look great.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Roughly speaking you can always have some `\if`-statements. However things become complicated if, say, your images are of different sizes and resolutions and you have a specific output device. For example, what do you expect if there is a 600dpi, 22cm-wide figure and your printer is of 600dpi? Probably you can fit that 22cm into `\textwidth` (about 14cm by default) but it would not be a good ratio. Setting `scale=.5`, at least in this case, might be better.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use the `adjustbox` package with its export option so it passes its keys to `\includegraphics` then use  `max width=\textwidth`

Comment: `max width=\textwidth` does not seems a right latex command. Did you mean `\includegraphics[maxwidth=\textwidth]{figure.png}`?

Comment: @user see adjustbox manual

Comment: I used this answer: [Includegraphics maximum width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96468/119062)

Comment: @user yes as Martin says there, as he says in the `adjustbox` manual, the key is `max width`, I am not sure what you are asking in these comments?

Comment: **`I am not sure what you are asking in these comments?`** On the first comment, I asked a question, you answered. End. On the second comment, I did not asked any questions, I just referenced/linked a answer I found related to this question.