# Set the max width of the image and does not stretch if smaller

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

Hi Is there any option in `includegraphics` in a way that I can specify the maximum width of the figure. If the image is larger than the specified width, it should be resized to its maximum width. Otherwise, it should retain its original size (not stretching!)

All the options I have tried stretched the smaller image to its specified max size :(

Comment: `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}\includegraphics[max width=somelength]{...}`should do it.

Comment: Bernard's suggestion and a couple others are also found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86350/, of which I guess your question is a duplicate?