# How to take figure width=\linewidth OR height=\pageheight?

Tags: floats, width, height

I want to include figures such that either width or height is used to adjust the document on the page. 
There are about 5\% of images where the height is dominating such that `width=\linewidth` causes overful. 
In such a case, I would like to adjust by `height=\pageheight`. 
Pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  % Make the decision here primarily by width; if overful, then height. 
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth OR height=\pageheight]{1.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: MWE?____________

Comment: @samcarter I added a pseudocode because I do not know if this possible what I proposed.

Comment: You're talking about latex. Everything is possible (maybe with an infinite amount of work, but possible). How dare you doubt latex?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just let the `graphicx` package have its way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %just to visualise the boarder

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-golden}

\newpage

\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-golden-upright}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I extended the new rotation part here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341551/13173 for the primary width.