# How to rotate image 90 if height overful?

Tags: graphics, conditionals, rotating, adjustbox

I think the approach can be with `adjustbox` but not sure. 
Pseudocode:

- *If height overfull, turn the image 90 degree clockwise, apply all images the width constraint now*
- *Do not pass max width (= `\linewidth`) in any case*.

In other words, preudocode

- If the image is too high originally, rotate it 90 so the biggest dimension will now be width. Scale the width to `width=\linewidth`.

Pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  % If image height overfull, rotate the image 90 degree clockwise. Apply now to it width constaint. 
  \includegraphics[if HEIGHT overfull, rotate 90 degree clockwise; width=\linewidth]{1.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i'm afraid this doesn't make sense, unless your document is landscape oriented, because that's the only way the width would have a larger dimension than the height.

Comment: if it is a tall image why do you want to rotate it so that you have to squeeze the large dimension of the image into the shortest dimension of the page???

Comment: @samcarter I think it is too early. The general case with big images is not solved. The images should be handled with relative proportions. I cannot get the proposals work with large images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a general approach that you can follow:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\imgbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \savebox{\imgbox}{% Store image in a box
    \includegraphics[height=<h>,width=<w>,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}%
  \ifdim\ht\imgbox > <H>
    % Do something to the box
  \else
    \usebox{\imgbox}%
  \fi
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In essence, you want to condition on the size of the included image. If it's too tall (or too wide), you may want to manipulate it otherwise. So, you store the image in a box (say, `\imgbox`), and then you can test the height - `\ht\imgbox` - or the width - `\wd\imgbox` against some other dimensions.

---

Specific to your application, you could do the following:

```
\begin{figure}
  \savebox{\imgbox}{% Store image in a box
    \includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}%
  \ifdim\ht\imgbox > \textheight
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{example-image}}}%
  \else
    \usebox{\imgbox}% Use resized image as-is
    % \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\imgbox}}% ...maybe resize to fit width
  \fi
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What is `<H>` in `\ifdim\ht\imgbox > <H>`?

Comment: @Masi: Whatever height you feel is the maximum. In your example, I'm guessing `<H>` should be `\paperheight`. Similarly, `<h>` and `<w>` is whatever dimensions you choose.

Comment: My `Do something to the box` can also be `Do something to the image`... like `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{example-image}}`.

Comment: @Masi: See update at the end of my answer.

Comment: I think my problem can be that I am not using standardised units. All my pictures are much larger than max textwidth and max pageheight. - - However, in such a case, the rotation should be applied, but I cannot see it.

Comment: @Masi: If all your images are much larger than `\textwidth` and `\paperheight`, then you can indeed use [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `max width` and `max height` options. These options only scale *down* if the image is larger, but not *up* if the image is smaller.

Comment: @gernot: Of course... multitasking here didn't help. Sorry, updated.

Comment: @Masi As far as I noticed from your other postings, your images are accompanied by a caption. But then `\textheight` is not a reliable indicator for an `overfull \vbox`, as the available space is in fact smaller. So you probably have to supply a bound manually.

Comment: This is the closest approach to the wanted solution solving most cases, but still not perfect with those rare huge images as described above. Still, I want to tick it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Does the following do what you want? The first normal `\includegraphics` produces an overfull `\vbox` (visible by the empty first page since the image is shifted to the second one), whereas `\includegraphicsoptrotate` rotates the image (and shrinks it to `\textwidth`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\graphicsheight
\newcommand\includegraphicsoptrotate[1][]%
   {\settowidth\graphicsheight{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
    \ifdim\graphicsheight>\textheight
      \includegraphics[#1,height=\linewidth,angle=90,origin=c]{#2}%
    \else
      \includegraphics[#1,width=\linewidth]{#2}%
    \fi
   }
\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-a}

\noindent
\includegraphicsoptrotate[scale=2]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: This method applies the rotation on all figures. I am thinking the if clause.

Comment: @Masi I think I don't quite understand what you really want. What about the remark by Barbara? If the image is too high, why should it fit when rotating it? Or do you want to check whether the image fits unscaled (optionally rotated), before scaling it? What has preference: minimal scaling or not rotating? If you answer these questions, please do it in your original posting, not in the comments. What does it mean for the image to be too high? Too high with regard to an empty page (=\textheight), or should it be scaled/rotated to fit it to a partially filled page?

Comment: I answered your question. It is much more simpler. Please, see the body.

Comment: @Masi I *think* that my solution now does what you have specified, by it's hard for me to imagine in which situation this is reasonable. Maybe you can adapt the answer to whatever you want.