# How to make a conversation with rectangle shapes using `tikzpicture` environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, numbering, positioning, draw

I am making a conversation and I need to draw some shapes, and place them properly along the page. The shapes are the following:

- A white rectangle with a little crest (called `mestart`):
  [image: mestart shape]
- A white rectangle without a crest (called `me`):
  [image: me shape]
- A green rectangle with a little crest (called `youstart`):
  [image: youstart shape]
- A green rectangle without a crest (called `you`):
  [image: you shape]
- A blue rectangle with rounded corners (called `exnumber`):
  [image: exnumber shape]

## What I want

I want to produce the following conversation:

[image: What I want]

To consider:

1. All the rectangles (except `exnumber`) can have inside:

   - Only text (normal text, bulleted list, numbered list etc.), or
   - Only one image (it can be a `tikzpicture`), or
   - Text & sample code (for instance `listings` package can be a good example).
2. These rectangles must have a max width and a space between them:
   [image: Max width]
   (also the images should have the same max width).
3. The blue rectangle i.e. `exnumber` should be placed centered on the page with an automatic numeration and restarted when the section ends. For example: in Section 1 `Exercise 1`, `Exercise 2`, `Exercise 3`. In Section 2: `Exercise 1`, `Exercise 2`.

## What I have done

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) [rounded corners=.2cm,inner sep=.3cm,align=right,fill=blue] {Exercise 1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) [draw,rounded corners=.2cm,inner sep=.5cm,align=left] {rounded rectangle\\asas};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) [rounded corners=.2cm,inner sep=.5cm,align=right,fill=green] {This is a rounded rectangle\\Text\\ a \\ a \\ a};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: What I have done]

**EDIT** Some changes to [edit #4 of the amazing Schrödinger's cat's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/529773/4) with some implementations:

1. Added `\maxwidth` and `\maxheight`.
2. Since I need to add a lot of images to the conversation, I have created four new types of shapes: the 4 ones but with the word `Image` after the names. This includes `\includegraphics[max height=\maxheight,max width=\maxwidth]{#2}`.
3. `\begin{varwidth}{\maxwidth}` added to the normal 4 shapes.
4. Added tabs space and some information to the code.

Final result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\def\maxwidth{16cm}
\def\maxheight{20cm}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.25in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Loads also graphicx
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/529773/4
\tikzset{basic/.style={rounded corners=.2cm,inner sep=.5cm},
    basic L/.style={basic,align=left,fill=white,anchor=north west,
        font=\sffamily,outer sep=0pt},
    my callout L/.style={basic L,
        append after command={pic[fill=white]{callout corner L}}},
    basic R/.style={basic,align=right,fill=green!60!black,anchor=north east,
        font=\sffamily,outer sep=0pt},
    my callout R/.style={basic R,
        append after command={pic[fill=green!60!black]{callout corner R}}},
    pics/callout corner L/.style={code={
    \path[pic actions] ([xshift=3mm]\tikzlastnode.north west) -- ++ (-9mm,0) 
    -- ([yshift=-6mm]\tikzlastnode.north west);}},
    pics/callout corner R/.style={code={
    \path[pic actions] ([xshift=-3mm]\tikzlastnode.north east) -- ++ (9mm,0) 
    -- ([yshift=-6mm]\tikzlastnode.north east);}},
    exercise/.style={rounded corners=.2cm,inner sep=.3cm,align=right,
        fill=blue,anchor=north,font=\sffamily,text=white},
    whatsapp/.cd,vdist/.initial=3mm,hdist/.initial=6mm
}
% Added varwidth to set a max width for each of the shapes. From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46479/152550
% MeStart
\newcommand{\MeStart}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) node[my callout L,alias=tmp,#1] {\begin{varwidth}{\maxwidth}#2\end{varwidth}};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
% Me
\newcommand{\Me}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) node[basic L,alias=tmp,#1] {\begin{varwidth}{\maxwidth}#2\end{varwidth}};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
% YouStart
\newcommand{\YouStart}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\textwidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) node[my callout R,alias=tmp,#1] {\begin{varwidth}{\maxwidth}#2\end{varwidth}};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
% You
\newcommand{\You}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\textwidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) node[basic R,alias=tmp,#1] {\begin{varwidth}{\maxwidth}#2\end{varwidth}};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
% Exercise
\newcommand{\Exercise}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\textwidth/2,0) node[exercise,alias=tmp,#1] {#2};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
% max height/width for includegraphics from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47252/152550
% MeStartImage
\newcommand{\MeStartImage}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) node[my callout L,alias=tmp,#1] {\includegraphics[max height=\maxheight,max width=\maxwidth]{#2}};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
% MeImage
\newcommand{\MeImage}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) node[basic L,alias=tmp,#1] {\includegraphics[max height=\maxheight,max width=\maxwidth]{#2}};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
% YouStartImage
\newcommand{\YouStartImage}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\textwidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) node[my callout R,alias=tmp,#1] {\includegraphics[max height=\maxheight,max width=\maxwidth]{#2}};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
% YouImage
\newcommand{\YouImage}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\textwidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) node[basic R,alias=tmp,#1] {\includegraphics[max height=\maxheight,max width=\maxwidth]{#2}};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[blue!20] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\MeStart{\blindtext[1]\\ Text}

\MeImage[scale=0.5]{example-image}

\YouStartImage[scale=2]{example-image-duck}

\Exercise{How many marmots?}

\You{\Blindtext[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Ti*k* has the `callout` shapes which look similar but not identical to what you have. Do you want the exact shape, or is something similar OK?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I want the exact shapes (it is like a WhatsApp Messenger conversation). Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This defines such shapes. Note that I did not really simplify positioning too much because probably you want some macros for the dialogue. They can take care of that. The following code is based on the newly added routines of your question. However, rather than defining many macros, it uses pgf keys. For instance, instead of

```
 \MeStart{\blindtext[1]\\ Text}
```

you can use

```
 \Me[start]{\blindtext[1]\\ Text}
```

or

```
 \You[start,image={scale=2}]{example-image-duck}
```

and so on. This has the advantage of being extendable very easily while keeping backwards compatibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\def\maxwidth{16cm}
\def\maxheight{20cm}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.25in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Loads also graphicx
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newif\ifStart
\Startfalse
\newif\ifImage
\Imagefalse
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/529773/4
\tikzset{basic/.style={rounded corners=.2cm,inner sep=.5cm},
    basic L/.style={basic,align=left,fill=white,anchor=north west,
        font=\sffamily,outer sep=0pt},
    my callout L/.style={basic L,
        append after command={pic[fill=white]{callout corner L}}},
    basic R/.style={basic,align=right,fill=green!60!black,anchor=north east,
        font=\sffamily,outer sep=0pt},
    my callout R/.style={basic R,
        append after command={pic[fill=green!60!black]{callout corner R}}},
    pics/callout corner L/.style={code={
    \path[pic actions] ([xshift=3mm]\tikzlastnode.north west) -- ++ (-9mm,0) 
    -- ([yshift=-6mm]\tikzlastnode.north west);}},
    pics/callout corner R/.style={code={
    \path[pic actions] ([xshift=-3mm]\tikzlastnode.north east) -- ++ (9mm,0) 
    -- ([yshift=-6mm]\tikzlastnode.north east);}},
    exercise/.style={rounded corners=.2cm,inner sep=.3cm,align=right,
        fill=blue,anchor=north,font=\sffamily,text=white},
    whatsapp/.cd,vdist/.initial=3mm,hdist/.initial=6mm,
    start/.is if=Start,
    image/.code=\Imagetrue\tikzset{whatsapp/graphics pars/.cd,#1},
    graphics pars/.cd,scale/.initial=1 %add additional keys here

}
% Added varwidth to set a max width for each of the shapes. From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46479/152550
% Me
\newcommand{\Me}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{whatsapp/.cd,#1}
\ifStart
    \path (0,0) (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) 
    node[my callout L,alias=tmp] {\ifImage
     \includegraphics[max height=\maxheight,max width=\maxwidth,
        scale=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/graphics pars/scale}]{#2}%
    \else
    \begin{varwidth}{\maxwidth}#2\end{varwidth}%
    \fi};
\else
    \path (0,0) (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) 
    node[basic L,alias=tmp] {\ifImage
     \includegraphics[max height=\maxheight,max width=\maxwidth,
        scale=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/graphics pars/scale}]{#2}%
    \else
    \begin{varwidth}{\maxwidth}#2\end{varwidth}%
    \fi};
\fi 
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
% You
\newcommand{\You}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{whatsapp/.cd,#1}
\ifStart
    \path (0,0) (\textwidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) 
    node[my callout R,alias=tmp] {\ifImage
     \includegraphics[max height=\maxheight,max width=\maxwidth,
        scale=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/graphics pars/scale}]{#2}%
    \else
    \begin{varwidth}{\maxwidth}#2\end{varwidth}%
    \fi};
\else
    \path (0,0) (\textwidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) 
    node[basic R,alias=tmp] {\ifImage
     \includegraphics[max height=\maxheight,max width=\maxwidth,
        scale=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/graphics pars/scale}]{#2}%
    \else
    \begin{varwidth}{\maxwidth}#2\end{varwidth}%
    \fi};
\fi 
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
\newcommand{\Exercise}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\textwidth/2,0) node[exercise,alias=tmp,#1] {#2};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[blue!20] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\Me[start]{\blindtext[1]\\ Text}

\Me[image={scale=0.25}]{example-image}

\You[start,image={scale=2}]{example-image-duck}

\Exercise{How many marmots?}

\You{\Blindtext[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good, thank you! As you mention, I surely will need macros for the 5 shapes since we are talking about like >40 pages.

Comment: @manooooh I added some sample macros.

Comment: I am wondering how did you get the space between shapes. That's awesome! Some inmediate comments: 1) when adding images wider than `example-image` or `example-image-duck` then picture is cropped, so I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47252/152550) and wrote a new command `\YouStartImage` which has `{\includegraphics[max height=20cm,max width=13cm]{#2}}` (the maximums can vary, it's just an example); so I call this `\YouStartImage{example-image}`.

Comment: 2) The `Start` shapes have a small imperfections wrt the crest: see [here](https://imgur.com/a/PDUIjoV), I will see if I can fix this or you can help me if you want.

Comment: 3) I am not able to move the white shapes more to the left and the green shapes more to the right (I want more space); I have tried changing both numbers in `\path (0,0) (1.5,0) node[...` but the maximum the white shapes can move to the left is when I change `(0,0)` to `(2,0)`; they don't move if I write a `>2` number in the first component. Could you see this problem, please?

Comment: @manooooh As for 1), I do not fully understand. As for 2), good catch! I forgot to set the `outer sep` to 0. As for 3), I introduced keys for that, now you can change the vertical and horizontal distances. The horizontal one cannot become smaller than 6mm at this point because the callouts have the corner of that length. However, you can use geometry to reduce the let and right margins.

Comment: Please take a look to my question edit! Do you like it? I love your code, that helped me to create the edit! More seriously, I hope with my edit you understand my comment 1). I realized that if the image is big, the edges get thicker (look the duck on the green shape). Can you achieve, starting from my code, the edges as thin as those of `example-image` have in the white rectangle if the image is big?

Comment: For aligning text on the right for the green rectangles we have to use `\raggedleft` inside the commands.

Comment: @manooooh Yes I like the output. The fact that the boundaries increase comes from  `scale=2` in `\YouStartImage[scale=2]{example-image-duck}`, which scales everything. If you do not want to have this, you need to pass the optional argument to `\includegraphics`, not `\node`.

Comment: Thanks. Uh, but I can have images that don't need to be scaled. I understand your proposal, is there a way to scale some images but not all images?

Comment: @manooooh I mean simply `\newcommand{\YouStartImage}[2][]{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) (\textwidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/hdist},0) node[my callout R,alias=tmp] {\includegraphics[max height=\maxheight,max width=\maxwidth,#1]{#2}};
    \path (tmp.south) ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/whatsapp/vdist});
\end{tikzpicture}\par}`. (Note the position of `#1`.)

Comment: I was going to indicate that (but I have used 3 arguments), so the argument that is inside `node` is useless for the 4 image shapes?

Comment: @manooooh I think that if you want to really do this, you should not have so many macros. Rather you should have pgf keys and automatization. What are the rules of this game? If I say something for the first time, is should be `\MeStart`, if the previous bubble was by me or an exercise, just `\Me`?

Comment: I don't know how to automate, that's why I created 8 commands + `Exercise`. But yes, if someone starts an exercise (i.e. after the blue rectangle) then we put `Me/YouStart`, the rest of the conversation (until another exercise) we only put `Me` or `You`. But I was planning to write the document manually... Don't worry!

Comment: @manooooh I added an example. It achieves what you achieve but with two commands and some pgf keys. The advantage is that you can keep adding options as needed and won't lose backwards compatibility. (Notice that one could add start automatically if this is the first post by "Me" or "You" in a thread.)

Comment: It looks better, you have removed unnecessary stuff. Why I can't change the image scale on `\Me[image={scale=<x>}]{example-image}` and `\You[start,image={scale=<x>}]{example-image-duck}`? (Remember to add `\raggedleft` for align text to the right.)

Comment: @manooooh My bad! Sorry! I thought I had understood how `\setkeys{Gin}{...}` works but apparently I do not. Added a temporary fix, will try to improve it later.

Comment: I am trying to include a `tabular` inside `\Me` box but when the context is too long the `tabular` does not break line. Try to add the following code to yours: `\Me[start]{Example:\\\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}\hline Text & This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text \\\hline\end{tabular}}`.

Comment: @manooooh Is using `longtable` something that you could consider? (I did not try out myself yet but I will only try if you are open to using it.)

Comment: Yes, why not? I just changed `\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}` by `\begin{longtable}{|c|p{\maxwidth}|}` (added `\usepackage{longtable}`) but the width of the `longtable` is still out of bounds. :(

Comment: @manooooh How about `\Me[start]{Example:\\\begin{tabular}{|c|p{\maxwidth}|}\hline Text & This is a very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very long text
\\\hline\end{tabular}}`?

Comment: [It still has the right side out of bounds](https://imgur.com/1AVmSdR.png).

Comment: @manooooh Sorry, my bad. Use `\usepackage{tabularx}` and `\Me[start]{Example:\\\begin{tabularx}{\maxwidth}{|c|X|}\hline Text & This is a very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very long text
\\\hline\end{tabularx}}`.